# Storing Tokens In The Most Secure Way

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

What is the most secure way to store tokens, if you are to roll out an ICO or similar? I know there are many ways, i.e. sharding the private key but what is the best practice right now? If I assign the total supply of a token to the msg.sender, what is the best way for me to ensure that my private key is protected.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are my thoughts on this topic:**

Don't store your private key or mnemonic on your machine if it is connected to the internet. This is a great target for hackers.

Over the years I have seen many different approaches. For example:

- Hardware Wallets
- Paper Wallets

However a cheaper option is storing the private key as an encrypted (password protected) text file on an USB-Stick. Keep in mind to unplug the stick when not in use. A downside to this is that in case your PC has a virus hackers still get your private key.

Another cheap alternative would be to just print your private key onto a sheet of paper (Make sure to hide it well).